Is possible to implement fpd-js (Fancy Product Designer - JS) using blazor server 8?
I have a website developed with blazor server 8 and i need to implement an image manipulator using fdp-js. Is posible to do it?
https://github.com/radykal/fpd-js
Thanks
I need to use an image manipulator to upload any images and also text into those images and te best way that I found was using fancy produt designer, but I have tried to use with blazor but no success
